# hibernate isnt joining the table correctly

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two tables, `Schedule` and `UserSchedule`. `UserSchedule` has columns `schedule_id` and `user_id`. What I want to do is something like this `select s from schedule s join user_schedule us on s.id = us.schedule_id where us.user_id = ?`. This works as intended if I run this query directly to db.

`Schedule` entity has `userSchedule` and all other necessary info

```
@Setter
@Getter
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "schedule_id")
@OneToOne
private UserSchedule userSchedule;
```

What's so weird is that I have `@Query("select s from Schedule s join s.userSchedule")` , and hibernate creates

```
select schedule0_.id as id1_10_, schedule0_.created_at as created_2_10_, schedule0_.end_date as end_date3_10_, schedule0_.end_time as end_time4_10_, schedule0_.frequency as frequenc5_10_, schedule0_.frequency_val as frequenc6_10_, schedule0_.is_active as is_activ7_10_, schedule0_.start_date as start_da8_10_, schedule0_.start_time as start_ti9_10_, schedule0_.updated_at as updated10_10_, schedule0_.description as descrip11_10_, schedule0_.lat as lat12_10_, schedule0_.lon as lon13_10_, schedule0_.project_id as project15_10_, schedule0_.title as title14_10_, (select v.status from voucher v where v.schedule_id = schedule0_.id) as formula1_ from schedule schedule0_ inner join user_schedule userschedu1_ on schedule0_.id=userschedu1_.id limit ?
```

The last part of the query `on schedule0_.id=userschedu1_.id` which should be I think `on schedule0_.id=userschedu1_.schedule_id`. Why tho? I can't seem to find any error.

Comment: why you even need the custom query if you already have a `@OneToOne` mapping?

Comment: because I really want to do is `select s from schedule s join user_schedule us on s.id = us.schedule_id where us.user_id = ?;` I found the problem is from join table, that's why I simplify the problem